Local minima of a multivariable function
Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function determined by $f(x,y) := (x^2+y^2) log(x^2+y^2)$. It is not hard to prove that all points in $C:= \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^{2} : x^2+y^2=1/e\}$ are critical points of $f$. Also, one can geometrically see that every point in $C$ is a local minimum:

However, the Hessian matrix criterion is not applicable since its determinant is zero at each point. How can we show analytically or algebraically that each point in $C$ is in fact a local minimum?

Each point of the circle $C$ is a global minimum of $f$:
$$f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$$ where $g(t)=t\ln t$, $g'(t)=1+\ln t$, hence $$\forall t>0\quad g(t)\ge g(1/e)=-1/e.$$
